# My Google Colab keeps crashing because of something in this code. Not sure what it is

Tags: pytorch, lstm, google-colaboratory

My google colab keeps crashing at train, even though RAM and disk are plenty. The problem is somewhere in this code, I think, but I don't know what it is. I am doing LSTM. I'd appreciate any help. I am using PyTorch.

This code is followed by generate function, encoder decoder class, etc. It is when I get to train that it crashes (for "unknown reason")

```py
class LSTMLM(torch.nn.Module):
  def __init__(self,
              vocab_size,
              embedding_size,
              hidden_size,
              num_layers=1,
              dropout=0.1):
    super().__init__()
    self.vocab_size = vocab_size
    self.embedding_size = embedding_size
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.num_layers = num_layers
    self.dropout = torch.nn.Dropout(dropout)

    self.embedding = torch.nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size)

    self.lstm = torch.nn.LSTM(input_size=hidden_size, hidden_size=hidden_size, num_layers=num_layers, batch_first=True)

    self.logistl = torch.nn.Linear(hidden_size, vocab_size)

    pass

  def forward(self, x, init_hidden_state=None):
    assert x.shape[0] == 1

    emb = self.embedding(x)

    emb = self.dropout(emb)

    if init_hidden_state is None:
      h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, 1, self.hidden_size)
      c0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, 1, self.hidden_size)
    else:
      h0, c0 = init_hidden_state
    output, (hn, hc) = self.lstm(emb, (h0, c0))

    hidden_states = output
    final_hidden_state = hn
    final_cell_state = cn
    final_state = [final_hidden__state, final_cell_state]

    hidden_states = self.dropout(hidden_states) 

    output_dist = self.logistl(hidden_states)

    return output_dist, hidden_states, final_state
```

Comment: It will be hard for someone to debug this without your data. I would recommend removing lines of code (and returning placeholder variables like `np.zeros()`) until you see exactly which line causes the crash.

Comment: I don't see any clear mistakes that would crash Colab. I think when you create your LSTM you're supposed to have `input_size=embedding_size` but that shouldn't crash Colab, it should give you a stack trace if it's incorrect (and if your `embedding_size` is the same as `hidden_size` it should still work).

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the crash.

Comment: @superbot You should consider adding the notebook link to your question so that everyone can see it immediately. As it is now the comment with your link will be hidden until you click on "Show all comments".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add cuda() after defining each tensor.

E.g.

```py
a = a.cuda()
```

Note that you must assign it instead of doing just `a.cuda()`